# What is wrong with using too many data types in database?

Tags: database, oracle, sqldatatypes

I've heard that it is not advisable to use too many data types in a database (Oracle).
what is the reason behind that?

Comment: I don't know of any limitations/drawbacks for doing so when necessary. Maybe you could ask for reasons to the person/blogger/etc. who told you that?

Comment: "Too many data types"? As in VARCHAR2, NUMBER, and DATE (the ones most often used)?

Answer (score 4):

You use the datatype appropriate for the data that you are storing. Using the correct data type acts acts as a necessary constraint on the type of data that can be stored and allows the data to be manipulated in desired ways.

There is no reason that I can think of for not using the appropriate datatype, so I do not think that there is such a thing as "too many".

Unless this refers to user-defined types?

Comment: I mean if we use like more than 5 or 6 data types will it affect the performance if queries? specially select statements?

Comment: No, but using the wrong datatype could affect query performance, data accuracy, and maintainability. In fact there are not really many common datatypes. DATE, VARCHAR2, NUMBER cover 95% of cases. TIMESTAMP and related types are fairly common I expect, BLOB and CLOB less so.

Comment: Be interesting to hear the context in which you heard this, and from whom.